# How to access UILabel without IBOutlets. Swift

Tags: ios, swift, view, uiviewcontroller

I want to change the backgroundColor for several labels without using an outlet.
If i set tag for UILabel i can this

```
 let label = self.darkView.viewWithTag(1) as? UILabel
        label?.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
```

But I want to do this for multiple objects and without a tag. I tried this but it doesn't work

```
if let labels = self.darkView.subviews as? [UILabel] { 
            
            for label in labels {
                label.backgroundColor =  UIColor.black
            }
            
        }
```

How i can implemented this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through all subViews of your custom view and check for each label like this:

```
for view in self.darkView.subviews as [UILabel] {
    if let label = view as? UILabel {
        label.backgroundColor =  UIColor.black
    }
}
```